# Open an user control as popup using jQuery dialog in ASPX page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, dialog, popup

I am trying to open an user control (Memo.ascx) as popup using jQuery dialog in an Aspx page.

ASPX:

```
 <td>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnMemo" runat="server"  AlternateText="Memo" CausesValidation="false"    
     OnClientClick="PrepareNOpenDialog()" ClientIDMode ="Static" />
    <div id="divMemoInfo" title="Memo"></div>
 </td>
```

JQuery :

```
$(function () {
      PrepareNOpenDialog(); 
});

function PrepareNOpenDialog() {

    $('#divMemoInfo').dialog(); //init the dialog (consider div as a dialog)
    $('#divMemoInfo').dialog('close'); //prevent the dialog from showing after initiation

    $('#divMemoInfo').load('Memo.ascx');

    dialogOptions = {
        modal: true
                , buttons: {
                    'Close': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
                , minWidth: 400
                , minHeight: 200
                , width: $(window).width() / 3 //'auto'
                , height: 'auto'
    };

    //open dialog when image clicked
    $('#btnMemo').click(function () {
        $('#divMemoInfo').dialog(dialogOptions);
    });

}
```

I am getting object expected error at **`onClientclick = OpenMemo()`**

Please advice.

Thanks

BB

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems one you are setting OnClientClick="OpenMemo()" but I don't see an OpenMemo() javascript function defined. It seems you already have a click handler for "btnMemo" so your OnClientClick="OpenMemo" should be deleted.

Your second problem is

```
$('#divMemoInfo').load('Memo.ascx');
```

This line won't work. The load method need a URL where it can retrieve the content from. You will need to wrap Memo.ascx in an aspx file and then call load with the URL of the aspx file. If you only need the contents of Memo.ascx then select the element it is encapsulated when the call is complete.

Comment: Thank you. I am stuck with the second problem. Could you please post some example or direct me to a source where I can find the solution for this.

Comment: Here is decent example http://www.aspxtutorial.com/post/2011/01/02/Load-aspnet-web-user-control-using-jQuery-and-web-method.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no javascript function called OpenMemo() (as an aside convention dictates function names start lower case)

Try creating a function like the following:

```
   function OpenMemo(){    
        $('#divMemoInfo').dialog("open");
}
```